# Scanning streamed data with clamav

Tags: streaming, netcat, clamav

I am trying to come up with a command with which I can scan a file by streaming it via network interface.

I have tried the following:

```
 telnet clamd.server.com 3310
 STREAM
 PORT <some random port>
```

Then on a different console

```
tar -czf - <some temporary files> | nc clamd.server.com <some random port>
```

The problem is that the `tar` command does not exit when the streaming is done and it stays there indefinitely or until the command is cancelled.

Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-N` to the `nc` command fixed the issue.

so

```
tar -czf - <some temporary files> | nc -N clamd.server.com <some random port>
```

Answer (score 1):

**clamd-stream-cl**
This is a modified version of clamdscan. It can stream a file to an intstance of clamd running on another host, via TCP socket.
-> http://sourceforge.net/projects/clamd-stream-cl/